# how to use Proguard and R8 shrinker in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, proguard, android-r8

I have created a react native app and then i have created the release apk by follow this link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android
My apk file is created but it's too large in size so i just find a solution on react-native official docs and try this following steps:

**def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true**
**def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true**
But, it not worked then i have learned about `R8 shrinker and Proguard`. So please tell me that can i use this for reduce apk file size in React Native and how to implement this on **react-native**

Comment: ref : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-r8-to-reduce-apk-size-in-android/

Answer (score 3):

Use `def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true` below `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true` in `android/app/build.gradle`. It will Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.